# How to animate movement of 3d models in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

The [3d model example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) in the Mapbox GL JS docs made me wonder how I could animate the movement of 3d vehicles across a map (e.g. Uber's [AVS demo](https://avs.auto/demo/index.html) and [Cesium](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGKAI7PzXgw)).

I tried adapting the 3d model example code by removing the current 3d model, creating a new one and then adding that.  However this cycle is much too slow for smooth animation:

```
const moveObject = () => {
  map.removeLayer('3d-model');
  modelOrigin = incrementCoords(modelOrigin);
  modelTransform = createModelTransform(modelOrigin);
  const customLayer = createCustomLayer(modelTransform);
  map.addLayer(customLayer);
};
```

Ideally I'd like to see smooth animation - like in the AVS demo or the various 'animate a [line](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-a-line/)/[point](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-line/)/[marker](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-marker/)' examples in the Mapbox GL JS docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a true 3D use case like in those demos, you'd be better off with a 3D tool rather than Mapbox GL JS. It's not a 3D renderer or true 3D so that's the reason you're not getting what you want. As for a Mapbox tool, the best option would be the [Maps SDK for Unity](https://www.mapbox.com/unity/).

There's an example in the Unity SDK of how to replace a 3D building with a custom model. You can find it here: https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/examples/replace-features/